# How to estimate an AR model which includes linear trend term in R?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

The `ar()` function in R performs estimation of an AR(x) model (an autoregressive model of order 'x') but I think it cannot include a linear trend term.
Are there ways to estimate AR models with linear trends using base R functions?

Comment: Use the `arima()` function with the linear trend in the `xreg` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is in the `Y` variable:

```
Y <- rnorm(100) + 0.4*1:100 #just simulating some data to exemplify
arima(Y,order=c(1,0,0),xreg=1:length(Y))
```

`xreg` includes covariates to the model, in this case, `1:length(Y)` is exactly a linear trend.